# How do I configure RemoteApp to find the correct Gateway Server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remoteapp, remote-desktop-gateway

I am trying to make RemoteApps work but when I go to the *https:\desktop.(mydomain)/rdweb* link from outside, all the apps that are published in the `QuicksessionCollectio` error out saying the server cannot be found.
If you look at the image loaded after clicking on a resource, you can see that the "Gateway Server" does not have the FQDN url for our gateway server. It should read **desktop.(mydomain)**.  What it currently says has no basis in reality. It is neither a server on the local domain nor the outside address of the gateway server and clearly a mistake I made when configuring the server. Where is that line generated? How do I correct it in the configuration? Everything else on the Remote Desktop Server works properly except Work Resources from outside. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I found the place where I made the mistake in Server Manager/Remote Desktop Services/Overview/Tasks Edit Deployment. The outside FQDN goes in the Server Name field. 
[image]